# navigation on a textmate page, front of line, end of line, up page etc

Tags: textmate

in textmate, when editing a .rb page (or any page), how do jump to the start/end of a line?
and what about to the top/bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the emacs key bindings in all cocoa text fields:

- `C-a` beginning of line
- `C-e` end of line
- `C-v` page down
- `C-p` previous line
- `C-n` next line

There are others, but these are the ones I most commonly use.

Comment: ⌘ ↑ (Command up-arrow) and ⌘ ↓ (Command down-arrow) scroll to the beginning and end of the current document, respectively.

Comment: ⌘→ and ⌘← move to the end and beginning of the line, as well.

Comment: Where "C" is the "control" key (not Command) I assume?  Is there a page up (opposite of C-v) that you know of?

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:

http://manual.macromates.com/en/key_bindings#text_move_edit_actions

Answer (score 0):

fn-opt-up and fn-opt-down also work for paging up/down and moving the caret. fn-up and fn-down without the 'opt' will page up/down **without** moving the caret.